# Webpage Fitting To Every Screen Reslution

Tags: javascript, html, web

I Use This Code To Automatically Detect Users Screen Resolution And Redirect To Another Page

```
<script>
if (screen.width==1367 && screen.height==768)
{
window.location="http://www.yoursite.com"
}
</script>
```

But For Every Screen Resolution I Cant Edit The Site.
Is It Possible That I Just Make Single Page That Can Automatic Fit To Screen.
Thank-You IN Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 media queries rather than javascript to detect the device and load the page accordingly.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  /* rules that only apply for canvases narrower than 1000px */
}

@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* rules for iPad in landscape orientation */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  /* iPhone, Android rules here */
}
```

You would also need to add the meta port view tag as below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries and specify different stylesheets for different screens.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

for example

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

For examples of already put up websites see: http://mediaqueri.es/

Answer (score 0):

'defau1t' is write. Also you can set it by css like=> "width:100%"; you can check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp too. Everything depends on your requirements.